# How to filter df using str.extract

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am relatively new to coding and I tried to challenge myself with a personal project which is proving a bit more difficult than I have anticipated :-)

I using a sale report that has both product info and product range information stored in the same column. I am trying to utilise the formatting of the column for filtering.

I am have filter my date using :

```
range_df = df[df['Stroke_Range_Det'].str.contains('(^\s{12})+([a-zA-Z]+)')]
```

which returned **Warning Message** "This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.  return func(self, *args, **kwargs)". Instead of ignoring the warning message, I have tried to use the `str.extract` but can't get the desired outcome.

I have tried the below code which didn't work.

```
range_df = df[df['Stroke_Range_Det'].str.extractall(pat = '(^\s{12})+([a-zA-Z]+)')]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

`extractall()` already returns a DataFrame.
Use:

```
range_df = df['Stroke_Range_Det'].str.extractall(pat = '(^\s{12})+([a-zA-Z]+)')
```